# NullPointerException after mock object in test

Tags: java, spring, scala, mockito

I have a getDefaultRetryInstance which can be used to retry a call when have exception

```
@Component
class VertexGetTaxResilience(var retryRegistry: RetryRegistry) extends Serializable {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
    val GET_VERTEX_TAX_RETRY_DEFAULT_NAME = "getVerTexTaxDefaultRetry"

    val defaultVertexRetryInstance = Retry.of(GET_VERTEX_TAX_RETRY_DEFAULT_NAME, retryRegistry.getConfiguration(GET_VERTEX_TAX_RETRY_DEFAULT_NAME).get())

    def getDefaultRetryInstance(): Retry = {
        // default retry instance configured in yaml
        logger.info("Retrieving default retry instance: {}", GET_VERTEX_TAX_RETRY_DEFAULT_NAME)
        defaultVertexRetryInstance
    }
}
```

I'm using this function.

```
val invoiceRequestResult = Decorators.ofSupplier {...}.withRetry(vertexGetTaxResilience.getDefaultRetryInstance())
            .get()
```

Here is how I do a mock for this retry object, but I got "java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown" above, how can I fix this?

```
 @Mock
 val vertexGetTaxResilience: VertexGetTaxResilience = null
 val retry = Retry.ofDefaults("getVerTexTaxDefaultRetry")
 //val vertexGetTaxResilienceMock = mock[VertexGetTaxResilience]
 doReturn(retry).when(vertexGetTaxResilienceMock).getDefaultRetryInstance()
```

Comment: How are.you using the mock after defining it? It has to be injected in the Spring context (assuming the `Component` annotation comes from Spring).

Comment: Hi @GaëlJ, the above code is all I did after define it, how can I inject it in Spring context?

Comment: please provide us with stacktrace (console output) that is shown when NPE is thrown

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fix this by using reflection for object.

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Likely you are not using the `MockitoJUnitRunner`. This is required for the `@Mock` decorators to work. If you don’t use it, the mocks will be `null`. Add `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class` to the unittest class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock a Spring component, so inside your test class inject this component mock as:

```
public testClass{
    
    @Mock
    private VertexGetTaxResilience vertexGetTaxResilience;
    
    //your test methods...
}
```

So now you can call methods from this mock

Comment: I modified the code, but I get this. Argument passed to when() is null!
Example of correct stubbing:
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
Also, if you use @Mock annotation don't miss initMocks()
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NullInsteadOfMockException: